# How to make a sentences to become 2 line using \thead

Tags: tables, makecell

I had try include `\thead` but not working.

I want to make `Class AA` and `Class BB` go into second line.

[image]

```
 \documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, justification=centering]{caption}


% \hypersetup{pdfborder = {0 0 0}}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=6.0, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=6.0cm}
 \begin{tabular}{lSS}
     \toprule
     \multirow{2}{*}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{\makebox[0pt]{Sample Number}}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
    &{\textbf{\thead{Testing1 species} \thead{(Class AA)}}}
     & {\textbf{Testing2 species (Class BB)}} \\
     \midrule
    High Wavenlength & {18, 17, 15, 18} & {19, 18, 1, 11} \\
    Medium Wavenlength & {18, 17, 18} & {19, 18, 11} \\
    Low Wavenlength & {18, 17, 15, 18} & {19, 18, 1, 11} \\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: With `\\ ` as in `\thead{Testing1 species \\(Class AA)}`.

Comment: Why do you use `S` type columns? You enclose all contents in a set of `{}` so, alignment via `S` columns is disabled anyways. Why not simply use `c` instead?

Comment: Isn't this question a duplicate to one of your previous question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `\theadfont` was redefined to include `\bfseries`, there is no need for `\textbf` in you alrady use the `\thead` command. To introduce the linebreak, just use `\\` inside of the `\thead` command. In the following MWE, I have also replaced the `S` type columns with regular `c` type ones. With this, your table will easily fit into the text width. I have also removed `\sisetup` from the table, since there is noting related to `siunitx` in this specific table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{lcc}
     \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Sample Number}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
     & \thead{Testing1 species \\(Class AA)}
     & \thead{Testing2 species \\ (Class BB)} \\
     \midrule
    High Wavenlength & {18, 17, 15, 18} & {19, 18, 1, 11} \\
    Medium Wavenlength & {18, 17, 18} & {19, 18, 11} \\
    Low Wavenlength & {18, 17, 15, 18} & {19, 18, 1, 11} \\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. I have a link question here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523598/are-we-able-to-make-centre-for-header-and-left-side-for-content-in-a-table