# Are we able to make `centre` for header and `left` side for content in a table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Are we able to make `centre` for header and `left` side for content in a table?

For `Testing 1 species, Class AA)`, is `centre` and good.
For `18, 17, 15, 18 and 18,17, 18 and 18,17`, can we move to left side?

I am using `table-number-alignment=center` for all.

[image]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\sisetup{table-format=6.0, table-number-alignment=center, table-column-width=6.0cm}
 \begin{tabular}{lcc}
     \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Sample Number}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
     & \thead{Testing1 species \\(Class AA)}
     & \thead{Testing2 species \\ (Class BB)} \\
     \midrule
    High Wavenlength & {18, 17, 15, 18} & {19, 18, 1, 11} \\
    Medium Wavenlength & {18, 17, 18} & {19, 18, 11} \\
    Low Wavenlength & {18, 17} & {19, 18} \\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `lll` instead of `lcc`.

Comment: Regarding: "I am using table-number-alignment=center for all.": This is irrelevant since this command will only influence the alignment of numbers in `S` type columns from `siunitx`. Since I already advised against `S` type columns (for this particular table) in your previous question, the only relevant part for the horizontal alignemnt of the contents are the column specifiers in `\begin{tabular}{lcc}` which currently tell you: first column left aligned, second column centerd, third column centered.

Comment: I have edited the tags, since the table in your qestion is unrelated to the `tabularx` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `l` (`l`eft)  type columns instead of `c`(`c`enter)  type columns for column 2 and 3. The headers will stay centered, since the default alignment of `\thead` is horizontally centered.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries} % for bold in table using \small
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage[svgnames, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{hhline, boldline}
\usepackage{seqsplit, caption} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{booktabs, ragged2e} % Use booktabs rules and get rid of vertical rules, ragged2e to ragged text
\usepackage{siunitx} %for table spacing to second row
\usepackage{threeparttable} %to add footnote below table
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[font=small,labelfont={bf,sf}, textfont={sf}, justification=centering]{caption}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
 \begin{tabular}{lll}
     \toprule
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Sample Number}}\\ 
     \cmidrule{2-3}
     & \thead{Testing1 species \\(Class AA)}
     & \thead{Testing2 species \\ (Class BB)} \\
     \midrule
    High Wavenlength & 18, 17, 15, 18 & 19, 18, 1, 11 \\
    Medium Wavenlength & 18, 17, 18 & 19, 18, 11 \\
    Low Wavenlength & 18, 17 & 19, 18 \\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, brillant!

Comment: Why you need `\sisetup` in the `table` float?, In table is nothing related to `siunitx`. Also word "species" more belong to caption (well, this table haven't it :-( ) or maybe to the first row, for example  `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Species Sample Number}}\\  `

Comment: @Zarko: You are definitely right. I have removed the `\sisetup` command. Regarding the "Spefies" part: I am not sure if "Testing1 species (Class AA)" is an actual column header or if it is just a placeholder, so I left it as it is.